# Why do the headphones not work on my HP Pavilion DV6?

Tags: 13.04, pulseaudio, headphones

Headset does not work on Ubuntu, but works on Windows and other distributions of Linux.

I have HP Pavilion DV6

[image]

Comment: Have you tried older distribution like Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you **edit your question** and provide more details? Like the Sound Card you are using? The output of `pulseaudio --check`, `pulseaudio --dump-conf`, `amixer -c 0`, `pacmd dump-volumes` and `pactl info`.

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine has a dv6-2153el, and he solved this problem running

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf
```

then rebooting.

If this doesn't work for you, you can undo with

```
rm /etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but, try unmuting them from the `alsamixer` (just type `alsamixer` in the terminal to run it).