# Why do not the brightness of the screen?

Tags: 13.04, software-center, brightness, hp

Brightness control problem

Show but it does not work

I have HP Pavilion DV6

I have Ubuntu 13.04

I want to control it through a software.

image

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BTDKLLiCQAAHQ9D.png:large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anythings else does not work, you can use [this software](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/). It just works.

Please note that it requires `python-wxgtk2.8` package installed, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Hi Archisman -I already installed the program, but does not open

Comment: @EmadHabib Install `python-wxgtk2.8`. The USC packagers still have not configured the dependency. Run this command in an Terminal `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8` and Brightness Controller will start working. **The dependency problem is already written in descriptions however**

Comment: Brightness works well :))

Comment: The application works fine after i install python-wxgtk2.8

Comment: visit : http://askubuntu.com/questions/339924/why-headphones-do-not-work-with-13-04?noredirect=1#comment433952_339924

Comment: @EmadHabib Sorry, I have no idea how to configure it. I took part in developing Brightness Controller,so I knew about it.

Comment: tnx :) Archisman

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal:

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line that says

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Press ctrl + o to save and ctrl + x to exit.
Then update GRUB by:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your PC and check your function keys. Post back if it doesn't work.

[Look here more help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1875126&highlight=GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=%22quiet%20splash%22)

Comment: Thanks user182904 for attention ,
But I followed the steps but it does not work :(

Comment: In order to see the changes, you've to restart the system ...
I've given the link below, use that link, it still problem persists, comment below .!!

Comment: [see here also] (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1875126&page=2&s=8f07198d9a63e2a20602a8aeabe0912c&highlight=GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT%3D%22quiet+splash%22)
_and also the link in the answer above_ ...!!

Comment: every thing is fine

Comment: visit : http://askubuntu.com/questions/339924/why-headphones-do-not-work-with-13-04?noredirect=1#comment433952_339924